# how to parse an image to using multiform data and alamofire url request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to send an url request with an image along with parameters using alamofire,multiformdata.When i am trying to send the request, i am getting an error like "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"at the line " imageobj = qrorimg.image!".If anyone helps me to do this,would be very great.Thanks in advance.

```
@IBAction func updatedetails(_ sender: Any) {



         productidstr = productid.stringValue
        imageobj = qrorimg.image!

        let acce:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access-tokenn")!
        print(acce)

        let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(acce)"]
        postParameters = ["name":name,"description":descriptionn,"location":address,"email":mail,"phone":phone2,"landline":land2,"validity_start":validstart,"validity_end":validend,"website":web,"offer":offer,"created_at":create,"id":productid]

     let ImageData = imageobj.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(ImageData!, withName: "photo", fileName: self.filename, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            for (key, value) in self.postParameters {
                multipartFormData.append(self.name.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "name")
                multipartFormData.append(self.descriptionn.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "description")
                multipartFormData.append(self.address.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "location")
                multipartFormData.append(self.web.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "website")
                multipartFormData.append(self.mail.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "email")
                multipartFormData.append(self.phone2.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "phone")
                multipartFormData.append(self.land2.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "landline")
                multipartFormData.append(self.validstart.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "validity_start")
                multipartFormData.append(self.validend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "validity_end")
                multipartFormData.append(self.offer.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "offer")
                multipartFormData.append(self.create.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "created_at")
               multipartFormData.append(self.productidstr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,withName: "id")
            }
        },to:(Constants.productupdate)+(productidstr),
          method: .post,
          headers: headers)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
                    print(response.request)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response) // URL response
                    print(response.data)     // server data
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                    //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
                    //self.removeImage("frame", fileExtension: "txt")
                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
                print(encodingError)
            }

        }


    }

}
extension ProductdetailupdateViewController:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:

        [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            qrorimg.image = image
        } else{
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let imgUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL{
            let imgName = imgUrl.lastPathComponent
            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
            let localPath = documentDirectory?.appending(imgName)

            var image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            let data = image.pngData()! as NSData
            data.write(toFile: localPath!, atomically: true)
            var photoURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)//NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)
            print(photoURL)
            photoURLstr = photoURL.path
            print("result \(photoURLstr)")



            filename = photoURL.lastPathComponent
            fileextension = photoURL.pathExtension  // get your file extension


            qrorimg.image = image
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Error clearly says `qrorimg.image` is nil, put breakpoint in `imagePickerController:` method and see `qrorimg.image` is set properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap the image first try this

```
if let aImage = qrorimg.image
```

and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this stuff using Cocoapods(Alamofire for request, SwiftyJSON for parsing, SDWebImage for image operations)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32232466)